# Google Cloud Speech API fails with 503

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I have developed a node.js application that uses Google Cloud Speech API and Vision API. I use the gcloud npm package for this. I use service account to connect to the api. When I run this locally everything works fine. But when I host this in Microsoft Azure the Google Speech API fails with a 503 Service Unavailable. The Vision API works fine but Speech API fails. Can someone say why this happens ?

I use the following code

```
speechClient.recognize(inputPath, {
   encoding: 'FLAC',
   sampleRate: 16000
}, function(err, transcript) {
   console.log("SPEECH TO TEXT ", err, transcript);
   callback(null, transcript);
});
```

And this what is printed in logs

```
SPEECH TO TEXT  { Error: Service Unavailable
at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:417:17 code: 503, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } } null
```

Comment: did you implement logging or something?

Comment: @AminEtesamian I have edited the question with the code and logs.